# An easier way to load a default slide (using css :target)

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a more elegant way of accomplishing something.

I have 5 slides on an html page. Each slide is a div with some content, and a back and next anchor tag that references the previous and next slides. The slides are positioned normally, statically that is. No special positioning, but I'm using a css animation to fade the slides in and out.

Here's the snippet:

```css
div.slide,
div.intro {
  max-width 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin 1em auto;
  padding 1em;
  text-align left;
  background: yellow;
}

div.slide { display: none; }

div.slide:target ~ div.intro { display: none; }

div.intro:target,
div.slide:target {
  display: block;
  animation: slidein 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% { opacity: 0; display: block; }
  1% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

div.intro a { margin-left: 2.35em; }
```

```html
    <div class="slide" id="slide-2">
    <h1>Two</h1>
    <a href="#slide-1">Back</a>
    <a href="#slide-3">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide-3">
    <h1>Three</h1>
    <a href="#slide-2">Back</a>
    <a href="#slide-4">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide-4">
    <h1>Four</h1>
    <a href="#slide-3">Back</a>
    <a href="#slide-5">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide-5">
    <h1>Five</h1>
    <a href="#slide-4">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div class="intro" id="slide-1">
    <h1>One</h1>
    <a href="#slide-2">Next</a>
    </div>
```

You should be able to click next and back and navigate through all the slides without display none interrupting the fade opacity too bad, but importantly, display none keeping the height of the page to just the height of the current slide.

At first, I had all the slides treated the same, but there's a URL problem. If the page loads without #slide-1 in the URL, it breaks. I need the URL to load the intro slide even without the #slide-1, as well as with it. The CSS accomplishes that, but only with the use of the general sibling selector, and by putting the intro slide last in the HTML, which sucks.

Is there a way of accomplishing the same thing without messing up the order in the HTML.

1. I want to have the intro slide first in the HTML.
2. I want the intro slide to show even if the URL doesn't have #slide-1 at the
   end, and also if it does.
3. No JavaScript ; )

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a pure `CSS` answer which satisfies all of your criteria.

- In the `HTML`, move the `id`s above the slide content
- Continue to hide all slides by default
- The `intro-slide`, by default, is set to `display: block`
- If *anything* is targeted, hide the `intro-slide`
- Override the previous bullet point's rule using the more specific:

```css
#slide-1:target~.slide-1
```

**Full code:**

```css
.slide {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
}

:target~.intro-slide {
  display: none;
}

.intro-slide,
#slide-1:target~.slide-1,
#slide-2:target~.slide-2,
#slide-3:target~.slide-3,
#slide-4:target~.slide-4,
#slide-5:target~.slide-5 {
  display: block;
  animation: slidein 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

div.intro-slide a {
  margin-left: 2.35em;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide-1"></div>
<div id="slide-2"></div>
<div id="slide-3"></div>
<div id="slide-4"></div>
<div id="slide-5"></div>

<div class="slide slide-1 intro-slide">
  <h1>One</h1>
  <a href="#slide-2">Next</a>
</div>
<div class="slide slide-2">
  <h1>Two</h1>
  <a href="#slide-1">Back</a>
  <a href="#slide-3">Next</a>
</div>
<div class="slide slide-3">
  <h1>Three</h1>
  <a href="#slide-2">Back</a>
  <a href="#slide-4">Next</a>
</div>
<div class="slide slide-4">
  <h1>Four</h1>
  <a href="#slide-3">Back</a>
  <a href="#slide-5">Next</a>
</div>
<div class="slide slide-5">
  <h1>Five</h1>
  <a href="#slide-4">Back</a>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zq4m9b5u/)

Comment: Haa, this is great. It does fill the requirements. The idea of pull the id's up is rather genius : )